# COUNT twice the same column

Tags: mysql, count, logic, percentage

I'm trying to count twice the same column with different conditions to at the end make a calcul to know a certain percentage.

The column is filled with several numbers from 1 to 10 and I would like to know the percentage of row where the number is superior to 6.

I had that idea to retrieve the numbers :

```
SELECT number, Sum(number> 6) as number_sup_to_6 FROM table;
```

But I would like after retrieving those to calculate the percentage of numbers superior to six to the numbers in total : ((n>6)/n)*100

I then took inspiration from a previous post to make the calcul :

```
concat(round(( number_sup_to_6 /number* 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage
```

Problem is, I don't know how to put those 2 pieces of sql together, could someone please help me how to understand how to combine them together ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this alternative for *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT SUM(t.number>6) / COUNT(t.number) AS ratio_num_sup_to_six
  FROM mytable t
```

Note that this *counts* the rows that have a number value greater than six, and *counts* the rows that have non-null values of number. This is equivalent to the result returned by:

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(t.number>6,1,NULL)) / COUNT(t.number) AS ratio_num_sup_to_six
  FROM mytable t
```

We can also express that in a more ANSI-standards compliant equivalent:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN t.number>6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
     / COUNT(t.number) AS ratio_num_sup_to_six
  FROM mytable t
```

If the goal is to get a *total* from the values stored in the `number` column (a SUM of the values rather than a COUNT of the rows), then something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.number>6,t.number,NULL)) / SUM(t.number) AS ratio_tot_sup_to_six
  FROM mytable t
```

---

**Formatting**

If we absolutely need to do the conversion from the ratio to a percentage for display in the SQL query itself (rather than the client), then we can wrap any of the expressions above in:

```
  CONCAT(ROUND(( expr )*100,2),'%')
```

For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(( SUM(t.number>6) / COUNT(t.number) )*100,2),'%') AS pct_num_sup_to_six
  FROM mytable t
```

Note that the return from the `ROUND` function is *not* guaranteed to include two digits after the decimal point. That is, we might get '22.2%'  or '50%' returned.

If it's important to return two digits after the decimal point (for display), we can use the MySQL `FORMAT` function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format

This will guarantee that two (or however many we want) decimal digits are returned, even when the digits are zero. So we can get '50.00' returned rather than '50'. (The bother with FORMAT is that it will also include comma separators for values >= 1000.)

---

**Performance**

This approach will be a single pass through the table, more efficient than other solutions that impose the extra overhead of materializing inline views (derived tables).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and also for your quick explanation between the same query with Sum() and Count(), it might come in handy later.

Comment: @Maxime.D: Note that the expression `t.number>6` will be evaluated as a boolean, which means MySQL will return a 1 for TRUE, return a 0 for FALSE, and return NULL when the condition evaluates to NULL. So doing a SUM on that expression is going to total up the 1s and 0s from each row, which is effectively equivalent to doing a COUNT. Rewriting that with an IF() function, or a CASE expression, makes it a little more clear what's happening. (The `SUM(t.number>6)` is a convenient shorthand allowed by MySQL.)

Answer (score 2):

Use CASE statement

```
SELECT number, (number_sup_to_6/total_count)*100 AS percentage
FROM
(SELECT number, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN number > 6 THEN number ELSE NULL END) AS number_sup_to_6, 
COUNT(number) AS total_count FROM table_name 
GROUP BY number) AS a
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll be sure to give feedback as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(( a.sum / b.sum * 100 ), 2), '%') AS percentage
FROM 
(SELECT SUM(number) AS sum FROM table WHERE number > 6) a,
(SELECT SUM(number) AS sum FROM table) b
```

Comment: Thank you for your really fast answer, unfortunately I do not have access to the database right now but I'll be sure to try your suggestion as soon as possible and give a feedback. I was unaware we could SELECT the variables after making the calcul in the query, your answer really open my eyes on a new way to handle MySQL. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @Darshan Mehta using CASE statement is best because in a single query you can count both over all number count and numbers which is superior to 6. and in your query there is 2 sub queries.